# careers profile views timezone

Tags: support, jobs, timezone

A couple of days ago I created a *career stackoverflow profile*. I'm looking daily to see if anyone has visited my profile. It says

> this week 7 visits, today 3

How is this counting? If I'm not wrong in other places/countries week starts on Sunday, here it starts at Monday. And what about timezones? When it says today it means past midnight at which timezone? I guess it isn't locally.

Comment: Stack Exchange uses UTC time.

Comment: I'd assume "this week" means "within the last seven days"

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thnx I guess this is obvious for some of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code used to generate these time periods.

```cs
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var thisMonth = now.AddDays(-30);
var thisWeek = now.AddDays(-7);
var today = now.AddDays(-1);
```

Since this is just candy data and not used as input to any other function, we just do a quick and dirty calculation.

Comment: Your hat is misplaced a bit :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard how's that? :)

Comment: Much better, and fitting! ;)